# How to correctly define ID and DateTime fields in Firebase Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am using Firebase **FireStore** database for the first time and I have the following question.

I have created a **calendar** collection. This collection will contains document representing events that have to be shown into a Calendar implemented by an Angular application.

So I am defining the following fields for these documents:

- **id**: int. It is a unique identifier of the specific document\event.
- **title**: string. It is the event title.
- **start_date_time**: string. It specifies the date and the time at which the event starts.
- **end_date_time**: string. It specifies the date and the time at which the event ends.

And here I have some doubts:

1. Is the **id** field required? From what I know I will have the document **UID** that will ensure the uniqueness of the document. If not strongly required adopt an **id** field can be convenient have something like an auto increment field? (I know that I have to handle in some other way the auto increment because FireStore is not a relational DB and doesn't automatically handle it). For example I was thinking that can be useful to order my document from the first inserted one to the last inserted one.
2. It seems to me that FireStore doesn't handle **DateTime** field (as done for example by a traditional relational database). Is this assumption correct? How can I correctly handle my **start_date_time** and **end_date_time** fields? These field have to contains the date time used by my Angular application? So for example I was thinking that I can define it as **string** field and put into these fields values as **2020-07-20T07:00:00** representing a specific date and a specific time. It could be considered a valid approach to the problem or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the id field required?

No fields are required.  Firestore is schema-less.  The only thing a document requires is a string ID that is unique to the collection where it lives.

There is no autoincrement of IDs.  That doesn't scale massively the way Firestore requires.  If you need ordering, you will have to define that for yourself according to your needs.

In general, you are supposed to accept the randomly generated IDs that the Firebase client APIs will generate for you.  Ordering is typically defined using a field in the document.

> It seems to me that FireStore doesn't handle DateTime field

Firestore has a timestamp field type that stores moments in time to nanosecond precision.  There is no need to store a formatted string, unless that's something you require for other reasons.